# Is it true in general for a continuous function $f$ and a non-empty set $X$, $\sup_{x \in S} f(x) < \sup_{x \in X} f(x)$ for a subset $S \subset X$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

If I have a continuous function $f$, is it true in general that:

$$
\sup_{x \in S} f(x) < \sup_{x \in X} f(x) 
$$

for a subset $S \subset X$?

Comment: No.  What if $f$ is constant.  It needs to be $\leq$.

Answer (score 2):

No; but, if you change it to the following, then yes:
$$
\sup_{x\in S}f(x)\leq \sup_{x\in X}f(x).
$$

To prove it: note that you need only show that $\sup_{x\in X}f(x)$ is an upper bound on $\{f(x)\mid x\in S\}$; and, this is trivially the case, because $\sup_{x\in X}f(x)$ is by definition an upper bound on $\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}\supseteq \{f(x)\mid x\in S\}$.